# How would it be possible to do something like this?

Tags: php

**I'm trying to place these in a seperate file that'll be included on every page**

```
$sql = 'select id, name, age, address, pincode from json where name = :name';
$arr = array(":name" => $name);
// There are some 30 diff sql's and arrays
```

**Another page**

```
$name = 'peter';
$conn = connect();

function myType(){
global $conn;
global $sql; 
global $arr; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($arr);

while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo $value.' <br>';
      }
   }
}

myType();
```

I'm trying to keep the sqls and arrays in a separate file and use them when needed. Keeps things clean and easy to maintain. But the variables are declared later, which gives me: `Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\web\apache\htdocs\dev\json.php on line 24`

Can you see a way to do this without uglying things?

Comment: Declare this as a function, that will return `$sql` and `$arr` (as an array); or as an object, having two methods.

Comment: There are several sql statements in that page.

Comment: why do you need to use globals? Try other methods of passing variables to function for example arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should use two files

1. sql.php
2. fetch.php

Then in fetch.php you will use `require_once 'sql.php'`

here's the code for fetch.php:

```
$name = 'peter';
$conn = connect();
require_once 'sql.php';
function myType(){
global $conn;
global $sql; 
global $arr; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($arr);

while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo $value.' <br>';
      }
   }
}

myType();
```

And this is sql.php

```
$sql = 'select id, name, age, address, pincode from json where name = :name';
$arr = array(":name" => $name);
```

This should be helpful and you can use sql.php whenever you like.

Comment: It the variable `$name` which is declared later that i'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the queries and there bound parameters in a separate include is a bit strange. How will you change the bound parameter after the include?

My suggestion is to create a model that will handle the database operations. The benefit of this is you can encapsulate the database work and keep it separate from your app logic and also easily reuse it throughout.

Basic example:

```
class CustomersModel
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getByName($name)
    {
        $result = array();
        $sql = 'select id, name, age, address, pincode from json where name = :name';

        if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql))
        {
            $stmt->execute(array(":name" => $name));
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
require_once('/path/to/CustomerModel.php');
$conn = connect();

$model = new CustomerModel($conn);
$customers = $model->getByName('peter');

foreach($customers as $c)
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($c['name']) . '<br />;
}
```